# invalid capacity 0 on image filesystem, Lens ID Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am creating k8s cluster from digital ocean but every time I am getting same warning after I create cluster and open that cluster in lens ID.

Here is the screenshot of warning:

[image: screenshot]

```
i did every soltion which i found but still can't able to remove the error.
```

Answer (score 12):

Check first if [`k3s-io/k3s` issue 1857](https://github.com/k3s-io/k3s/issues/1857#issuecomment-950154218) could help:

> I was getting the same error when I installed kubernetes cluster via `kubeadm`.
>
> After reading all the comments on the subject, I thought that the problem might be caused by `containerd` and the following two commands solved my problem, maybe it can help:
>
> ```bash
> systemctl restart containerd
> systemctl restart kubelet
> ```

And:

> This will need to be fixed upstream. I suspect it will be fixed when we upgrade to containerd v1.6 with the cri-api v1 changes

So checking the `containerd` version can be a clue.

Answer (score 1):

1. you can restart containerd service. this will fix the problem.
2. To make permanent fix, set SystemdCgroup = true in /etc/containerd/config.toml and make sure that kubelet is configured to use systemd cgroup driver. you can check in /var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml file

[containerd config screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hM6XB.png)

then restart the containerd service,